# redux-devtools-extension layout in devtools no longer responsive or resizing

Tags: google-chrome, redux, google-chrome-extension, redux-devtools

Silly question, but I can't find any reference to this issue online other than an unanswered subreddit thread.

Sometime within the last few weeks, the layout for the redux-devtools-extension in devtools stopped being responsive. I used to be able to resize the window, and the panels would stack on top of each other, or the panels would get wider to adjust for the changed window width. Now, it's completely static, and a lot of info is hidden unless I get my window really big.

Chrome is fully updated, redux-devtools-extension is fully updated, and there are no issues applying it in the redux store. Does anyone have any ideas??

The screenshot shows how a good chunk of the right panel ("State") is covered and the layout doesn't adjust when there's overflow.

[image]

Comment: It's obviously a bug. The only question is where: in devtools, in Chrome, or in the extension.

Comment: The bug is in the extension. This was indeed introduced in the past few months, track https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/issues/1294 for the latest info.

Comment: @NathanBierema Thank you. Couldn't find this anywhere.